# Angular cookie expires but back button brings it back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using angular's cookie library to set a cookie used for storing the id and passcode of a shopping cart cookie stored on the back end.  After purchasing the cart I am trying (and succeeding) in expiring the cookie by setting the expiration date to a previous date.  I have confirmed multiple times that it is gone, but when I click back to the original buy page the Cart is loaded using the same passcode and id, extracted from the cookie.  Can anyone think of how this is possible?  I am out of ideas.  I provided the code below.

in buy page:

```
$cookies.put('scId', injectedScId);
```

in order receipt page:

```
$cookies.put("scId", "expired", [{ expires:"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT" }] );
$cookies.put("scPc", "expired", [{ expires:"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT" }] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why expire a cookie? Why not remove it with $cookies.remove("scId")?

Where is your $cookies.put('scId', injectedScId) call. Is it in a add to cart click handler? If it is just in the controller constructors logic then you would expect the cookie gets set. It is impossible for someone to know what is going on from your question.

Comment: I have tried $cookies.remove as well but it does not fix it.  The $cookies.put('scId', injectedScId) call is in the controller associated with teh buy page.  So not on add to cart click handler.